# Why does this bat file not execute properly?

Tags: batch-file

I need to add a subkey in the registry of Windows 10 with a .bat script, but the results are not what is expected. Code does produce a result, but creates an incorrect entry. I need a subkey named **EnableLinkedConnections** that is of the type: REG_DWORD with a data value of 1

I have already written a .bat to add entries which are correct, but trying to add another in a different registry folder creates an incorrect entry.

```
@echo off
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\" /f /v "EnableLinkedConnections" /t REG_DWORD d/ 0x1
pause
```

This creates a folder outside of the System folder, but still in the Policies folder named:

**System" /f /v EnableLinkedConnections /t REG_DWORD d/ 0x1**

which is not correct. I expected a subkey entry of type REG_DWORD.
Seems that its having an issue with backslashes maybe, but the other .bat I wrote does not do this, so a bit stumped. Any pointers welcome.

Comment: I see a Typo: `d/`.

Comment: You seem to have your terminology mixed up, because it seems as if you're wanting to add `/D`ata of a particular `/T`ype to a `/V`alue within a sub key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` with a root key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` under the key `Computer`. `@Reg Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /V EnableLinkedConnections /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F>Nul`. Note you would likely need to run this as administrator too.

Comment: I see an even more important typo `System\"` where the backslash before the quote causes the entire remainder of the command line to be treated as the name of the key that is to be added.

Comment: Thankyou, I will update and retry with this information